# Cannot reach LDAP server from Windows Server docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have the following code that uses an LDAP address to find a user via AD & the groups the user belongs to.

```
using var ldapContext = new DirectoryEntry(_configuration["ActiveDirectory:Path"], username, password);
using var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldapContext);
searcher.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={username}))"; 
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
      try
        {
            List<string> groups = new();
            foreach (SearchResult entry in searcher.FindAll())
                if (entry.Properties.Contains("memberOf"))
                  ...
```

Running this works fine, until I try running it in a Docker container. Then I get the simple error message:
`"The server is not operational."` The DC server is reachable from the container.

The Dockerfile is the standard one created by the VS template, but with the Windows Server Core tag.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.9-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 AS base
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/services/identity/Identity.Api.Service/Identity.Api.Service.csproj", "src/services/identity/Identity.Api.Service/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/services/identity/Identity.Api.Service/Identity.Api.Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/services/identity/Identity.Api.Service"
RUN dotnet build "Identity.Api.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Identity.Api.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.Api.Service.dll"]
```

Does it have to run under another image or is there some kind of extra configuration that needs to be done when running in Docker?

Complete StackTrace:

```
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) 
in /_/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices
/DirectoryEntry.cs:line 561

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) 
in /_/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/DirectorySearcher.cs:line 623

at Identity.Api.Service.Controllers.IdentityController.LoginViaActiveDirectory(String username, String password)
```

Comment: Be sure to check out https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42914. Not sure if you're having the same issue as that but worth checking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was host related, when I tried running the service as a docker container in the production environment it worked just as expected.

I suspect that there's some underlying host issue since my own machine is running Docker via WSL2 & in production it is running natively on Windows Server 2022.